# html script blank page when run

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I'm trying to debug an experiment written in JS & html. I'm running an html template that imports JS codes. But all I get is a blank page when I run it in chrome. I checked whether my chrome preference allows javascript to be run.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Name Face Association Task</title>
  <script defer src="/Users/jasonlim/Downloads/MTurk_Experiments-master/NFA/static/lib/jquery-min.js" type="/Users/jasonlim/Downloads/MTurk_Experiments-master/NFA/text/javascript"></script>
  <script defer src="/Users/jasonlim/Downloads/MTurk_Experiments-master/NFA/static/lib/underscore-min.js" type="/Users/jasonlim/Downloads/MTurk_Experiments-master/NFA/text/javascript"></script>
  <script defer src="/Users/jasonlim/Downloads/MTurk_Experiments-master/NFA/static/lib/backbone-min.js" type="/Users/jasonlim/Downloads/MTurk_Experiments-master/NFA/text/javascript"></script>
  <script defer src="/Users/jasonlim/Downloads/MTurk_Experiments-master/NFA/static/lib/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

  <!-- jsPsych Plugins -->
  <script defer src="/Users/jasonlim/Downloads/MTurk_Experiments-master/NFA/static/jsPsych/jspsych.js"></script>
  <script defer src ="/Users/jasonlim/Downloads/MTurk_Experiments-master/NFA/static/jsPsych/plugins/jspsych-instructions.js"></script>
  <script defer src="/Users/jasonlim/Downloads/MTurk_Experiments-master/NFA/static/jsPsych/plugins/jspsych-html-keyboard-response.js"></script>
  <script defer src="/Users/jasonlim/Downloads/MTurk_Experiments-master/NFA/static/jsPsych/plugins/jspsych-survey-html-form.js"></script>
  <link href="/Users/jasonlim/Downloads/MTurk_Experiments-master/NFA/static/jsPsych/css/jspsych.css" rel="stylesheet" type="/Users/jasonlim/Downloads/MTurk_Experiments-master/NFA/text/css"></link>

  <!-- additional functions -->
  <script defer src="/Users/jasonlim/Downloads/MTurk_Experiments-master/NFA/static/js/supplementary-functions.js"></script>
  <script defer src="/Users/jasonlim/Downloads/MTurk_Experiments-master/NFA/static/js/questionnaire.js"></script>

  
  <!-- psiTurk 
  <script defer src="/Users/jasonlim/Downloads/MTurk_Experiments-master/NFA/static/js/psiturk.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    // These fields provided by the psiTurk Server
    var uniqueId = "{{ uniqueId }}";  // a unique string identifying the worker/task
    var adServerLoc = "{{ adServerLoc }}"; // the location of your ad (so you can send user back at end of experiment)
    var mode = "{{ mode }}"
  </script>
  -->

  <!-- experiment -->
  <script defer src="/Users/jasonlim/Downloads/MTurk_Experiments-master/NFA/static/js/NFA.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <noscript>
    <h1>Warning: Javascript seems to be disabled</h1>
    <p>This website requires that Javascript be enabled on your browser.</p>
    <p>Instructions for enabling Javascript in your browser can be found
    <a href="http://support.google.com/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=23852">here</a></p>
  </noscript> 
</body>

</html>
```

My psiturk is not able to be downloaded, so I commented out all the code related to psiturk and tried running it in plain html instead.

Comment: What's the expected result when the browser does run JS?

Comment: Please note that from everything we can see in your question the HTML output should really be blank. This is at least true for people who do not know what MTurk Experiments is. Does one of the sourced scripts have a running part? If not, it is missing a starting point like `<body onload="someObject.someFunction(event)">`.

Comment: @DSCH it should run a standard JsPsych experiment, starting with instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your server does not have a path like `http://example.com/Users/jasonlim/....` :)

You should open your [browser's devtools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools) (<kbd>F12</kbd>) to see the errors. It would have told you that those files cannot be found.

You need to make those paths relative to the current page (something like `static/lib/jquery-min.js` or `lib/jquery-min.js` depending on where your HTML file is located), or when running a local HTTP server you can make them relative to the root of the domain (e.g. `/lib/jquery-min.js`).

Plus, you have invalid `type` attributes. The MIME type for JavaScript is `text/javascript` and not `/Users/jasonlim/Downloads/MTurk_Experiments-master/NFA/text/javascript`. Same goes for the style tag, the MIME type should be `text/css` and not `/Users/jasonlim/Downloads/MTurk_Experiments-master/NFA/text/css`.

You can check the documentation about [`<script>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp) and [`<style>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_style.asp) here. Also, take a look at [this tutorial](https://www.pixemweb.com/html/html-file-paths-absolute-vs-relative-urls/) to understand relative and absolute URLs.

But, it appears to me that you are looking at this the wrong way in the first place. According to the [psiTurk documentation](https://readthedocs.org/projects/psiturk/downloads/pdf/stable/), you need to use the `psiturk` tool (for example with the `debug` command) to test your experiment locally, not by opening the HTML file manually. Your comment says "These values are provided by the psiTurk server" but if you just open the HTML files, there is no such psiTurk server, and you will have variables *actually* containing `{{ uniqueId }}` for example, instead of the ID that the server would normally put there...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. A colleague who is familiar with psiTurk told me that if I want to run the psiturk experiment without psiturk (my computer is unable to download at this point), I can just comment out all the pstiurk code and run it in html, and the code should work fine.

Comment: Ah, OK that is probably true, but then still you need valid paths to the scripts and styles that you use.

Comment: if I want to debug the experiment without psiTurk, should I upload my experiment folder to the web, like Box so I can write paths relative to my current page?

Comment: If they are in the same folder as the HTML file, e.g. `myscript.js` will do. If the script is in a subfolder like `lib` compared to the HTML file, `lib/myscript.js` is what you need. But in general yes I'd advise to use an HTTP server because this avoids a number of oddities that you may run into. You don't need to upload it though, you can use a local server. Check out [Mongoose](https://www.cesanta.com/binary.html) (the free features are enough) - just put it into your project's folder and run it. (To shut it down again, check your systray for the icon, right-click it and choose "exit".)